# How do I write testing within the context of a RESTful JSON API microservice?

Tags: rest, microservices, backend

Within the context of a RESTful JSON API microservice, what different types of tests would you typically recommend/use, and what is the purpose of each type?

Answer (score 0):

A RESTFul API is nothing but an API that can be invoked on Http.
Just write test cases that you normally write for an API, i.e. mock the data inputs and verify the expectations of individual classes or end to end flow.